# issue on running Flutter project from android studio in iOS simulator

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, cocoapods

I am trying to run my flutter project in an ios simulator 14. But I am facing the below issue when ever I run the project from android studio.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

My cocoapods version is 1.12.0 and below is my locale showing in terminal.

```
ios % locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First makesure what kind of bash file you are using by typing command "echo $SHELL"
   % echo $SHELL
   /bin/zsh
   , e.g i use zshrc.
2. for my example, I add

   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
   export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

into my .zshrc file
and restart whole IDE and it will be solved.

Second method is for when you install both cocoapods from homebrew and gem. Uninstall both and reinstall using
sudo gem install cocoapods
refer to this link https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html